# Android custom listview click - How to call an intent without crashing?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, clickable

All right, so I've been a few hours on this, and can't get it to work.
Basically, I wanna call an intent from a clickable listview. I'm displaying car models and it's code on a list, when you click, you're supposed to be taken to another screen to edit the car's properties, however, I'm beggining to think it's impossible

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayListCarros);  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
    db.close();

    mainListView.setClickable(true);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Intent i = new Intent(listagemcarro.this,com.example.trabalhosql.edicao.class);  
            startActivity(i);



      }
    });
```

The rest of the code:

```
    public class listagemcarro extends Activity {
Button buttonCadastro;
Button buttonListagem;
Button buttonBusca;
Button button1;

Intent itListagem = new Intent();
Intent itCadastro = new Intent();
Intent itBusca = new Intent();
//Intent itEdicao = new Intent();
Intent itEdicao2 = new Intent();

String id="";   

public SQLiteDatabase db;
public String BANCO = "banco.db";
public String TABELA = "carro";
int posicao=123123;

private ListView mainListView ;  
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

public void toast(int position){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show(); 

}
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listagemcarro);

    Intent itRecebeParametros = getIntent();
    if(itRecebeParametros != null){
        id = itRecebeParametros.getStringExtra("id");
    }


    db = openOrCreateDatabase(BANCO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor linhas = db.query(TABELA, new String[] {"ID_PESSOA, MODELO"},"id_pessoa = '"+id+"'", null, null, null, null);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  

    ArrayList <String>arrayListCarros = new ArrayList<String> ();  

    if(linhas.moveToFirst()){ 
        do{
            arrayListCarros.add(linhas.getString(0) +" " + linhas.getString(1));
        }
    while(linhas.moveToNext()); 
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, arrayListCarros);  
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );      
    db.close();

    mainListView.setClickable(true);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Intent i = new Intent(listagemcarro.this,com.example.trabalhosql.edicao.class);  
            startActivity(i);



      }
    });

}
```

error

```
11-19 23:18:09.136: W/dalvikvm(1784): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-19 23:18:09.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trabalhosql/com.example.trabalhosql.edicao}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.example.trabalhosql.edicao.onCreate(edicao.java:42)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-19 23:18:09.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     ... 11 more
```

edicao.class

```
package com.example.trabalhosql;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class edicao extends Activity {

String id="";   
String modeloCarro = "";
TextView textViewCarroEscolhido;

public SQLiteDatabase db;
public String BANCO = "banco.db";
public String TABELA = "carro";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listagemcarro);

    Intent itRecebeParametros = getIntent();
    if(itRecebeParametros != null){
        id = itRecebeParametros.getStringExtra("id");
        modeloCarro = itRecebeParametros.getStringExtra("modeloCarro");
    }

    textViewCarroEscolhido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCarroEscolhido);
    textViewCarroEscolhido.setText(modeloCarro);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I'm guessing that this part of the edicao class is incorrect:

```
setContentView(R.layout.listagemcarro);
```

That itself might not have thrown the error, but trying to finding views (like your textView) in it that don't exist would.

Comment: can you post the `OnCreate` of `edicao.class`? what is on line 42? there seems to be something there.

Comment: Ok, I editted my post with the code, but I dont think the edicao.class is a problem, I can intent and call it through a normal button perfectly.

Comment: Christ, it works... I should stop my copy and paste, always gets me into troubles =/      But anyways... How come it worked fine if I called the activity from a button?

Comment: glad^^. sorry for the initial mistake. the error comes when you try to set text to the in-existing textView. `.setText(modeloCarro);` maybe when you set up the button listener, that command wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

textViewCarroEscolhido is null. Make sure that it exists in listagemcarro.xml

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here for calling intents in drawing situations such as canvas. Ensure you are not calling the intent multiple times. In my situation the `invalidate()` method kept getting called and made many intent calls. Ensure to use some sort of flip mechanism to stop `invalidate()` from being called. Will work like a charm.